# Team Foundation Server (TFS) Can't connect to team project

Tags: tfs

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional. I have successfully downloaded code into source control for the first time using TFS. It's all there; I can see it. In Team Explorer it says at the top, "You have not connected to a team project in this team project collection." Fine, so I click on "Connect to a Team Project" and am asked to connect to Team Foundation Server, which I do, but I still am not connect to a project. I see an option to "Create a New Team Project." Do I have to do that first? In short, what is the process for connecting to a project for the first time?

Comment: Where in source control did you download to? Did you not create a team project first? Someone must have created a team Project in order for you to put code in TFS.

Comment: No, I (a TFS newbie) did not create a team project, I just downloaded the code to a local directory. I realized this was probably wrong and have deleted it all and will start over. What is the process in brief? Thanks!

Comment: Is your TFS Server on your premises, or are  you using Visual Studio Online?

Comment: Can't find docs quickly, but create a team project (File->New->Team Project). That will, among other things, give you a place to put code. Then, use Team Explorer to connect to the Team Project. It will tell you to map a folder (workspace). Do that, then you can create projects in that workspace. Doing so will give you the option to "Add to Source Control".

Comment: I suggest you start with a sandbox team project to use while you learn TFS. Once you're ready to do real work, you may decide to learn from your mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take your advice.